# AS2 detect when SWF is closed

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Is there a script in AS2 that will call a function when the SWF is closed? I found solutions, but they're all in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the SWF being viewed? In browser, standalone?

Comment: It would be posible to detect when the browser or the browser tab has been closed but what about in standalone? Thanks. :)